# Escape single quote in command argument to sh -c

Tags: linux, terminal, sh, 7zip

I am trying to send a command to another terminal. I've learned that I need to use `sh -c` to send the entire command in once. The command itself is to compress a file using [7-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) (command-line executable `7z`). Here is an example:

`7z a Aa.zip Bb.txt`

So the entire command would be

```
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip Bb.txt'
```

This works without any issue. The problem is when there is a single quote (`'`) in the filename to be compressed, e.g., `B'b.txt`. So, the command becomes

```
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip B'b.txt'
```

which does not run in the terminal.

These are the commands that I tried without any luck:

```
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip B'b.txt'
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip B\'b.txt'
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip B'"'"'b.txt'
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip "B'b.txt"'
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip \"B\'b.txt\"'
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip \"B'b.txt\"'
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip B'\''b.txt'
```

Running these commands result in either this error:

```
Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

or waiting for input

```
>
```

which I then cancel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

I also tried using a variable and then pass it to `sh -c`. Again without any luck:

```
cmd="'7z a Aa.zip B'b.txt'"
echo $cmd
'7z a Aa.zip B'b.txt'
sh -c $cmd
a: 1: a: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

What am I doing wrong?

<sub>I know this question might sound familiar and may be similar to other questions like
*[How can I escape quotes in command arguments to sh -c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758773/how-to-escape-quotes-in-command-argument-to-sh-c)*
and many others. But none of the methods marked as answer to these question work for me. So, please bear with me.</sub>

Comment: In most  cases, a here-document will solve your quoting problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip "B'\''b.txt"'
```

This: `'\''` is an escaped `'` as a part of the string. You need that for the `sh` command itself. Once you've started running the command, leaving the `'` unmatched causes a problem, so you need to put it inside of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest reading through this [shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html) article.

For your case, specifically

> A backslash cannot be used to escape a single-quote in a single-quoted string. An embedded quote can be created by writing, for example: `'a'\''b'`, which yields `a'b`. A single token can be made up of concatenated partial strings containing all three kinds of quoting or escaping, thus permitting any combination of characters.

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sh -c "7z a Aa.zip B'b.txt"
```

or

```
sh -c '7z a Aa.zip B'"'"'b.txt'
```

Or just, you know, use a (Bash or [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell)) array.

```
cmd=(7z a Aa.zip B'b.txt)
sh -c "${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: The array approach doesn't work here exactly as-given; it's equivalent to `sh -c '7z' 'a' 'Aa.zip' $'B\'b.txt'`, so all the words other than `7z` end up populating `$0`, `$1`, etc which are promptly ignored.

Comment: ...for bash 5.0+, maybe `sh -c "${cmd[*]@Q}"`? But you'd also need to fix the syntax used when _assigning_ the array, as the single quote isn't in double quotes or otherwise escaped, and is thus in a context where it's treated as syntactic rather than literal.

Comment: For your first solution, you have to escape the single quote so that `sh` should not interpret as a quote